# How to calculate inventory using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I am looking for a way to calculate stock quantity from two tables.

My table records are as follows:

Below is my product table

[image]

I have two table first is "stockinward" for purchase the stock and another is stockoutward for sale out the stock.

Below is the screenshot for stockinward table

[image]

and here is the screenshot for stockoutward

[image]

Below is my query to calculate the stock

```
SELECT 
p.Id,
p.Name,
p.UnitPrice,
((SELECT 
        IFNULL(SUM(Quantity), 0)
    FROM
        stockinward
    WHERE
        ProductId = p.Id) - (SELECT 
        IFNULL(SUM(Quantity), 0)
    FROM
        stockoutward
    WHERE
        ProductId = p.Id)) AS Quantity
```

FROM
    product p;

[image]

But the issue is in above query, when i have more then 1000 products it takes more then 8 second, so is there any other way in which i get the same result in 1 or 2 seconds?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Let's do that again, but without any pictures

Comment: if you use MS SQL server instead of MYSQL you'll see a big change in speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use joins instead of subqueries

```
SELECT 
p.Id,
p.Name,
p.UnitPrice,
IFNULL(qin.Quantity, 0) - IFNULL(qout.Quantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM product
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM stockinward
    GROUP BY ProductId
) qin ON p.Id = qin.ProductId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ProductId, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
    FROM stockoutward
    GROUP BY ProductId
) qout ON p.Id = qout.ProductId
```